# Test manager error message customization

Tags: c#, tfs, microsoft-test-manager

is it possible to replace error message generated by Test manager with our own custom message using c# code or using any other alternate solution?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to update result in database without C# Code, you win in performance.

Target `table is in Tfs_Warehouse, DimTestResult table`, contains outcome information of the test run.